# What is 'Delivered' and 'Derived'?

Tags: derived, peoplesoft

Can someone explain to me in detail what it means when something is delivered and when something is derived.

Thanks buddies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume we are talking with respect to PeopleSoft. we call an object 'Delivered' if it comes as a part of Peoplesoft suite and not customized or modified. 'Derived Record' is a type of record in peoplesoft which we use online when we don't want to store the value in database.

Comment: Derived records are also often used to store Peoplecode libraries and reusable functions.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're really talking about Peoplesoft (as you tagged your question) a Derived (aka Derived Record) is a non persistent data structure in a component buffer. So you will not commit its content to the database when saving process occurs.

Concerning the delivered part of your question, well it doesn't really make sense to compare with derived record. You deliver package, project or pizza :)